# Class Not Found Exception With JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA in order to create my Web Application. I have created a project that has a package called `com` with four subpackages, one of which is called `util`. This package (`util`) contains a class called DatabaseUtility which gets a connection instance. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class DatabaseUtility {

    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection != null)
            return connection;
        else {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auction", "root", "password");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }

    }
}
```

When I debug this file I get thrown into the catch block with a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` error. I already added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar to the External Libraries folder.

This exact code will work when this class is in the default package, but once I add it to a package, this error occurs. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate since this question pertains to Intellij, not Eclipse.

Comment: But mots important is, does it answer your question?

Comment: http://nixmash.com/java/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-fix-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: The linked question contains some answers that are IDE agnostic, and you should be able to infer what you need to do in IntelliJ as it is very similar.

Comment: add mysql-connector-bin jar to external lib